# Kendo ui grid parameterMap Cannot read property 'field' of undefined

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid. I am doing SERVER SORTING In parameter map when sorting **at third click I have the error**:  Cannot read property 'field' of undefined  `option.sort[0`] is undefined
Why?

Comment: for all fields you have get this error? you use foreign key field?

Comment: parameterMap: function(option){ option.sort[0] is undefined at third click. And I cannot send to the server post.... why? At third click I should have field name with dir asc. How can I rename the fild?

Answer (score 1):

The third click gets to unsorted state which means the sort array is empty. Hence getting its first item returns undefined.

Comment: Yes. I just neede to add sortable: allowUnsort:false . I resolve it! Thanks!